# How to share a datamodel between the master and detail of UISplitviewController?

Tags: swift, ipad, model-view-controller, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got a `DataModelController` class which both the `master` and `detail` of my splitviewcontroller  need to access simultaneously. The problem is that I can't just create an instance in each of them because **I need the two data models to be the same**.

I could create a `DataModelController` object in the `master` and then reference it in the `detail` but I don't know how to get access to it from code.

My architecture is:

```
                   / NavigationController (detail) - ViewController
Splitviewcontroller
                   \ NavigationController (master) - CollectionViewController
```

I'm using Xcode with Swift.

Since it was requested here is a minimal version of the code, detail:

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController {
    // I need to set this to the dataModelController of NotePreviewCollectionViewController
    var dataModelController: DataModelController!
}
```

and master:

```
class NotePreviewCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let dataModelController = DataModelController()
}
```

Comment: Share a minimal version of the code that helps reproduce the issue. It's help provide quick and accurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to share data is to let the data look after its own life cycle rather than tying it to the classes that use it.

```
class DataModelController {
    static let instance = DataModelController()
    private init() {
    }
}
```

This way each class that needs the data model gets the one consistent version by referencing `DataModelController.instance`.

Comment: I have read about this approach and it would definitely work but as far as I understood it, using singletons is discouraged / considered bad practice.

Comment: They're a type of tool.  If you were to avoid them because someone says they're always bad, you wouldn't be able to use Apple's frameworks.  Depending on what actual problem you think singletons cause, there's likely an implementation that avoids it.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t make this too specific but here’s one way to do it with delegation:

Delegate

```
protocol ModelDelegate {
    func updateModel(object: Any) // Make this whatever type you need
}
```

Master

```
class MasterViewController: UICollectionViewController, ModelDelegate {
    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    let dataModelController = DataModelController()

    func updateModel(object: Any) {
        // this will be called from Detail controller
        // Update model
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDis etail" {
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.dataModelController = dataModelController
            controller.modelDelegate = self
            detailViewController = controller
        }
    }
}
```

Detail

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var dataModelController: DataModelController!
    var modelDelegate: ModelDelegate?   
    // Whenever you want to update your model
    modelDelegate?.update(object: obj) // Pass changes back to Master
}
```

What you're doing here is passing a reference of your data (either a part or the whole object) to your Detail Controller. Whenever you want to update the model, call the delegate.